# How to write zsh/python filename expansion with backreferences?

Tags: python, zsh, glob

I have the files with following structure

```
env1.current/bin/env1/fileName
env2.current/bin/env2/fileName
env3.current/bin/env3/fileName
env4.current/bin/env3/fileName
```

How do I list all the above files? Something similar to below?

```
ls (.*).current/bin/\1/fileName  #Doesn't work!
```

Is it possible in to list those in python? The [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module doesn't support backreferencing.

Comment: Have you considered `os.walk`?

Comment: `os.walk` would be very slow as I might have to walk through a very big network drive. Wish there is a smarter way

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pick up on the network drive thing. It might be worthwhile to edit that information into your post

Comment: If you want to do this in a zsh shell, you can do this: `ls env*.current/bin/env*`. Or, `ls **/*`, which is shorter. The question is unclear: you seem to be asking about a method to list files in `python`, not in your shell.